# Unable to display user input

Tags: android, user-interface

I am building an Android todo list app that uses SQLdatabase for saving user input(task, time, date) but facing a weird problem, when i try to update the default textview with user input only one of the 3 textview changes,who's id is mentioned 1st with the one input read at last leaving rest textview unchanged.

**update_titleUI**

```
public void update_titleUI() {
    ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID, TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE},
            null, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE);
        taskList.add(cursor.getString(idx));
    }

    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                R.layout.item_todo,
                R.id.task_title,
                taskList);
        mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(taskList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}
```

**update_timeUI**

```
public void update_timeUI() {
        ArrayList<String> taskTime = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
                new String[]{TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID, TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TIME},
                null, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TIME);
            taskTime.add(cursor.getString(idx));
        }

        if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    R.layout.item_todo,
                    R.id.task_time,
                    taskTime);
            mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            mAdapter.clear();
            mAdapter.addAll(taskTime);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
```

**update_dateUI**

```
public void update_dateUI() {
    ArrayList<String> taskTime = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID, TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_DATE},
            null, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_DATE);
        taskTime.add(cursor.getString(idx));
    }

    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                R.layout.item_todo,
                R.id.task_date,
                taskTime);
        mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(taskTime);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}
```

**The output comes when i am declare update_titleUI 1st and update_dateUI at the very end**
[image: The output comes when i am declare update_titleUI 1st and update_dateUI at the very end]

Comment: one problem I see is, that, if your adapter is null, You create a new one and set it to list, but You don´t call notifyDataSetChanged(). Only an assumption, but if your adapter is null while your listView is opened, you won´t see the update....

Comment: how should i do it

Comment: I don´t really understand your way you are doing this. Is it correct, that You save all informations in different tables? It looks like because you are using one adapter for every view. It is more easy to store everything in one table and retrieve everything in one cursor...